# Disable mouse double click using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which i have some text boxes and below to it there is a table.When i double click on table row it takes me to another page.

Now the problem is if i double click on text boxes also it is going to another page so,i need to disable mouse clicks on this text boxes and also used tr for header and another tr for data.when i click tr header also it should n't work.

Note:

i have many text boxes so making each one double click mouse disabling is n't good solut.If i click row with data alone that double click should work.

Comment: you must be binding to more than just the table then, or your textboxes are children of the table. Code would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a `class='myClickDisabledElm'` to **all DOM elements** whose clicks you want to stop.

```
<input type="text" class="myClickDisabledElm" />
```

now javascript

```
jQuery('.myClickDisabledElm').bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

**Edit**

Since you are more concerned abt double click you may use `dblclick` in place of `click`

Comment: as far as i understand ur problem, you can replace click with "dblclick". Or provide more info.

Answer (score 24):

it should be like this

```
$('.myTextBox').dblclick(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: this will happily double submit a form if applied to a button :/

Answer (score 5):

As said [here](http://b-p-i.blogspot.ro/2017/11/javascript-to-disable-double-clicking.html), use a capture phase event listener:

```js
document.addEventListener( 'dblclick', function(event) {  
    alert("Double-click disabled!");  
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation(); 
  },  true //capturing phase!!
);
```

Comment: Rather `onmousedown` in Firefox 108.

Answer (score 1):

Got the following code from [here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/01/disable-mouse-double-click-using-javascript-or-jquery.html)

jQuery code to disable double click event on the webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("*").dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });   
    });
```

Above jQuery code will disable double click event for all the controls on the webpage. If you want to disable for specific control, let's say a button with ID "btnSubmit" then,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnSubmit').dblclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable any mouse click action use   addEventListener(event, function, useCapture) .

Onclick ,call this function.

For more refer here.:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp