# jquery mouse double click on text box not preventing values from browser cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-cache, double-click

I have a Date Input text box generated by jquery Date Picker which is only meant to display dates from the current date.

However if a user has used the form previously, he is able to choose previous dates generating from which on double clicking displays a choice of dates from his browser cache.

This would help a user book dates that are prior to current dates. I am solving it using a sever side check. However is there a way I can prevent this. I tried preventing double clicks based on all suggestions in this link, but no avail

1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241981/disable-mouse-double-click-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `autocomplete="off"` to your `<input>` element. This will prevent the browser from showing previously entered values.

You should also validate the date server side to ensure nothing slips through the client side net.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put your dateinput in the `<form>` you submit your search with, but populate a hidden input on submit. You will not be able to prevent browsers from caching data of your dateinputs if they actually are part of the form submit your search with.