# Disable mouse double click using class(es) with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable double click for some elements and the best way would be to use a special class for that.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241981/disable-mouse-double-click-using-javascript-or-jquery) simple and short jQuery solution that is exactly what I want, but I need pure JavaScript code.

Possible? Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been so long since I did straight jQuery free javascript but what you would want is something along these lines

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClassName");

for (var element in elements){
    element.ondblclick = function(e){
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var element in document.getElementsByClassName('disable-click')) {
    element.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response.

Comment: I would not advice to use this. If the element had an `onclick` handler defined, this will overwrite it, and you cannot restore it (if you would like to). In simpler code, it will not matter though.

Comment: You're welcome. This also prevents single clicks, but you said that the code in the question you linked to does exactly what you need, so i assumed preventing single clicks works for you.

Comment: @bažmegakapa well the point is to prevent the old behavior so i guess this shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: It helps, I (will) modify it to get what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @padde Hm, `prevent` and `destroy` is not really the same. If you write an application, you might want to disable some behaviour only temporarily. You might not want to get rid of the old behaviour, just prevent it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa now i see what you mean. yes you are right, this might be a concern, but it does not emerge from Omegas question that he needs to restore the old handlers.

Comment: @padde Well, there isn't a lot emerging from his question. Maybe except his high IQ :).