# How do I prevent double-clicking on mobile menu icon?

Tags: javascript

I have created this navigation menu:

https://codepen.io/dtommy79/pen/xxXYQdr

When i click on the mobile menu icon, the menu opens and the icon is changed into X. When I click the X, the menu closes. However, when I double click on the menu icon, the menu opens (the way it's supposed to), but the icon changes back to the default (closed) state.

I was thinking maybe disabling double click could work (maybe I'm wrong), so I tried to use eventlistener with `dblclick` event.

I also tried some of the jquery suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241981/disable-mouse-double-click-using-javascript-or-jquery).

I'd need a pure js solution preferably.

Comment: What was wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366432/8317237) answer? That one doesn't use any jQuery features.

Comment: @N. Kern
I tried that too, but did not have any effect for me.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event#browser_compatibility) isn't compatible with some mobile browsers. You could try using a global variable to hold the time of the most recent click event, and only toggle the menu if the time between clicks is > some threshold.